# NET MAUI Json Deserialization

Tags: json, maui

All Respected Members,

I have a question regarding deserialization of the JSON object that pull from REST API.

```
async Task LoadEmployee()
{
    try
    {
            string url = "http://192.168.103.11/employee_detail.php";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                HttpContent content = response.Content;
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeModel>(result);
                Console.WriteLine(empname);
            }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Model

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string empname { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the JSON response from POSTMAN from REST API

```
[{"empname":"JHON DOE"}]
```

And this is the API in PHP

```
<?php
require_once('koneksi.php');
$myArray = array();
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT empname FROM master_karyawan WHERE emp_id='M0000'")) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
    }
mysqli_close($conn);
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```

During the debug, the app throw an error at

```
var emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeModel>(result);
```

But there a JSON response returned in this line of code

```
string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Anyone can help to point what is the problem?

Comment: instead of "an error" please post the **specific error message**

Comment: Just making sure, you know that Microsoft prefers you to use `System.Text.Json` and its JsonSerializer class which offers both serialization and deserialization over third party packages such as `Netwonsoft.Json`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: @StephenQuan thank you for your highlight, i have change to JsonSerializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[]` in the `[{"empname":"JHON DOE"}]` means it's a collection not a single model. And according to your api code, you passed an array of the model. So you can try the following code:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     HttpContent content = response.Content;
     string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     var emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeModel>>(result);
     EmployeeModel model = emp[0];
     Console.WriteLine(model.empname);
 }
```

Comment: I see, i need to hold the deserialization in a List<> Object.

Thank you so much for the help.